# How to use mongoDB container in docker compose with flask

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, docker-compose

I'm trying to connect all my services by using docker compose. All my services are connected except mongoDB. Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
  user_service:
    build: ./user_service
    ports:
     - "83:83"
    links:
     - mongo
    depends_on:
     - mongo
    volumes:
     - .:/code
  mongo:
    image: "mongo:latest"
    ports:
     - "27017:27017"
    command: mongod --port 27017
```

In my flask app I try to have access to the database with the following code:

```
mongo = MongoClient('mongo://mongo', 27017)
db = mongo['user-database']
users = db.users.find({})
```

These lines of code doesn't work because my user_services doesn't find the mongoDB service.

Comment: Is your flask app is `user_service`? If you run flask app locally, than you need to expose mongodb from the container, and connect to the container ip address. If you run flask in the `user_service`, try to establish a name for the mongo, and run the service application in the container.

Answer (score 2):

In your MongoClient change the code to following

```
import os
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request, render_template
from pymongo import MongoClient
mongo = MongoClient( os.environ['DB_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR'],
            27017)
```

Reference [article](http://containertutorials.com/docker-compose/flask-mongo-compose.html)

This could be done using the mongodb linked container predefined environment variables that becomes available upon linking to user_service and use it in MongoClient.

Note: Check the environment variables available to your user_service container  for the particular version of Mongodb container linked.

Comment: I tried this before and it didn't work. I use the docker ip address

Comment: Modified the answer have a look

Comment: Is this up-to-date for version 3?